# How to pass the color and size in SubmitFeed Amazon MarketPlace

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

I have tried lot of the time in Submit Feed (product) in Amazon Marketplace. There is a lack of clear information and the reference document is also not good as much. It is have only the basic feed submission.

I need to create new product with size and color information. Please the code below,

```
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>5000-***-**-*</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>UPC</Type>
        <Value>YSjsjs899ss</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
      </Condition>      
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Backout T-Shirt Light Pink Medium</Title>
        <Brand>Blackout T-Shirt</Brand>
        <Description>This is an sample product added by bala.</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Made in Italy</BulletPoint>
        <MSRP currency="USD">2.19</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>Peacock Alley</Manufacturer>
        <ItemType>Novelty T-Shirts</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
            <Size>M</Size>
          </VariationData>          
          <SizeMap>Medium</SizeMap>
          <ColorName>Light Pink</ColorName>
          <ColorMap>pink</ColorMap>   
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Underwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>mens</Department>
            <ModelNumber>CM203</ModelNumber>
         </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
```

But it is not working. Please guide me to do this.

Regards, 
Balaganesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this answer is late, but I just had another question today that led me here, and while this didn't help me, I believe I can answer this question anyway. So here goes:

You can find the XSD -- which is the xml schema file -- here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/ProductClothing.xsd

The special thing about this, which is different from JSON is that this has the `:sequence` attribut. This means that **it is important which order the elements go into the xml file**.

In the `ColorSize` variation theme, the VariationTheme block should look like this:

```
<VariationData>
  <Parentage>child</Parentage>
  <Size>S</Size>
  <Color>White</Color>
  <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
</VariationData>
```